# Difference between difference in counts

Tags: time-series, poisson-distribution, count-data

I have some count information on sales spread across four 6-month time periods. A change was made to the layout of the shop in the final period and I want to see if there was a difference in sales associated with this intervention.

I could use a poisson means test to compare period 3 against period 4, or perhaps a better option would be to compare period 2 against period 4 as they are the same 6 months of different years.

If I had more data I would consider using a regression model but I don't think I have enough data to do so in this case (I'd have to include variables for year, part of the year, Intervention).

I feel I should compare the change between period 1 and 2 against the change between periods 3 and 4 but I haven't been able to find an appropriate test and it would miss any natural uplift across years.

Here is some example data:

```
Period, Count, Intervention,
1, 10187, No,
2, 12892, No,
3, 12124, No,
4, 14722, Yes
```

Comment: You wou.ld probably be better off formulating as a regression problem.  Alternatively, use ANOVA after the square root transform (which is variance stabliizing for the poisson distribution).

Comment: Thanks @kjetil-b-halvorsen, would regression on a dataset this small not lead to over-fitting if I included terms for year, period, intervention?

Comment: If its too small for modelling, then it is too small for testing!  Include the variables you need to include, and then be carful with testing, use exact methods, use bayes methods   (bootstrapping is generally no good solution with small datasets, as it is an asymptotic approximation)